# iOS Storyboard UIViewController switch back & forth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

The basic design of app storyboard goes like this:

Top Level#1
   Navigation Controller --> View Controller (Front) contains button "Show Master"

Next Level#2
   Navigation Controller --> View Controller (Master) --> push --> View Controller (Detail)

When I run the app in simulator, Front View Controller page appears.

Requirement: On "Show Master" button click, I wanted the control focused to Master. When something done here, either show Detail view Controller or swing  back to Front view Controller. How to code this from Front.M and Master.M.

Setup: iOS 6.x, XCode 5.x
   Note: Below code exists in Front.M but it does not work, brings up Master page in black

```
vwMaster *vc = [[vwMaster alloc] init];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're most of the way there, but that `vwMaster` has no layout information associated with it. One way to provide this would be to create a .xib file with the same name as your view controller class (i.e. vwMaster.xib) and set the xib file's owner to `vwMaster`. Your existing code should then work.

It seems like you're using Storyboard, however, in which case you have several options:

1. The easiest option. In Storyboard, ctrl-drag from the button in the Front view controller to the Master view controller. select a modal segue type.
2. Create a modal segue between the Front and Master view controllers in Storyboard by ctrl-dragging between them, give the segue an identifier (e.g. "vwMaster") in the attributes inspector and trigger the segue in code:

   ```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"vwMaster" sender:self];
   ```
3. Give the vwMaster view controller itself an identifier in the identity inspector in storyboard and present that as you were before:

   ```
   vwMaster *vc = (vwMaster *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vwMaster"];
   vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
   ```

Regardless of the route you choose, you're likely to want use the delegate pattern to dismiss your view controller. For this and more, I suggest you read the relevant apple Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

if you use navigationcontroller y u no use push and pop instead presenting viewController?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **knellr**.

I have been playing with different flows. I am able to goto view by calling

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"name" sender:self] - provided  name'm.
```

Also have strong code handling - in cases where data to be passed out

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
    }
}
```